# How to pass a parameter on NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, pug

I started to learn NojeJS literally today and I'm having some trouble to pass an id as parameter on .pug.

I'm trying to do:

```
ul
    each movie in movies
        li
            a(href='/movies/view/#{movie.id}') #{movie .nome}
```

And:

```
 app.get('/movies/view/:id', function(req, res){
  connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM ' +table+ ' WHERE id = "' + req.params.id + '"',
    function(err, results, fiels) {
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
      res.render('singular_movie', {
        filme: results,
        title: results[0].name
      });
    }
  )
});
```

When I try it in the browser instead of the number of the id I got just this: {movie.id}. I'm watching old videos about Node, perhaps that's the problem. Could anyone help?

Comment: If you use "' + req.params.id + '" it wont take the parameter.Use like this "SELECT * FROM  table WHERE id = ' "+req.params.id +" ' ";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
href='/movies/view/#{movie.id}'
```

This is old behavior that's been removed in recent versions. Try this instead:

```
a(href='/movies/view/' + movie.id)
```

More in the issue here:
https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2302